# Securing Cable when installing old work box

Tags: wiring

I am installing an electrical outlet above a gas fireplace for TV.  I understand that electrical code requires securing the NM cable within 12" of outlet box.  I am curious how one goes about achieving this in a finished wall being that there is really no room to get hand, hammer, drill or screwdriver inside the wall through that box opening.   I am sure this is straightforward for experienced electricians but I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: I take it the NM cable was fished through the stud bay to the box location?

Answer (score 5):

You're off the hook:

> NEC 334.30(B)(B) Unsupported Cables. Nonmetallic-sheathed cable
>   shall be permitted to be unsupported where the cable:
>   (1) Is fished between access points through concealed
>   spaces in finished buildings or structures and supporting is impracticable.

Comment: Agreed no staple needed for this.