# How to handle existing electrical when adding a partition wall where two existing wall switches exist?

Tags: electrical, framing, multiway-switch

[image: moving switch question]
[image]

I'm adding a wall to turn a loft into a bedroom.  The new framing will be right where an existing junction box is.

Coming into the box from the top right are two 14/3 romex cables for a 3-way hallway ceiling light to the right in the image.  I want to move the switch a few inches to the right so it's outside of the new bedroom.

**Can I drill a hole in the stud right above the current j box, add a  <s>new work box</s>  old work box on the other side of the stud, and simply feed the existing cable through the new hole into the new box?  My concern is that there would not be any staples since I do not have full access to the right side of this stud.**

Comment: "I do not have full access to the right side of this stud." What do you mean by this? The simplest solution there is to cut a hole in the drywall for an *old work* box and then drill a hole into that cavity from the open section and feed your wires in (can use the jbox hole you just cut to reach in and grab them). Is there another consideration there?

Comment: @Machavity - That was my mistake, I meant to say "add an old work box" as you mentioned.  By "not having full access" - I mean there is drywall covering that area that I'd prefer not to rip out.  I can add an old work box and reach in and grab a wire as you mentioned.  My only concern with that approach is my inability to staple the cable within 12" of the box - which I believe is required by NEC code 314.17(C).  I can pull a cable, put an old work box in, but will I fail to properly secure and fail my inspection without a staple?  Really it all comes down to the staple, am I being silly?

Comment: Moved second question regarding the 2x 14/2 nm cable at the bottom of the image here - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/209687/how-to-handle-a-break-in-a-circuit-due-to-removal-of-a-fixture

Comment: Just remember every occupyable room must have a light switch that works.

Comment: It will have a light switch, outlets, windows with egress, a closet, etc. - just not a light switch right in the middle of a stud!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's answer the second question first (quoting from your comment)

> My only concern with that approach is my inability to staple the cable within 12" of the box - which I believe is required by NEC code 314.17(C).

Old work boxes have push-in clamps which *secure the wire to the box*. It's equivalent to a NM clamp on a metal box. Compare them to new work boxes sometime. Some feature that same clamp, but many merely have a break-out tab. That's where you need a staple, but since you have to attach it to a stud, your wall has to be open in some way in the first place.

> Can I drill a hole in the stud right above the current j box, add an old work box on the other side of the stud, and simply feed the existing cable through the new hole into the new box?

Not really. You're going to lose 3-4" off your wire doing that, meaning they won't reach the location of your new box. The only solutions here are

1. Gain access from above. If the wires are running just right, you can drill a hole in the top plate, pull the existing wires back, and drop them into your new box. This is unlikely but still possible.
2. You'll need a second old work box above the new one somewhere. Drop the existing wires in and add new wires from this box to the switch box. Nut nut the wires off and then blank plate it. Not ideal, but you avoid re-running the wires. Doing this towards the top of the wall will be less obvious.

Comment: I might have confused myself here. I now see both NEC 314.17(C) and NEC 334.30. Your answer seems to apply to 314.17(C) - meaning an old work box has built in clamps to properly secure the cable.  Which is great!  But now I'm seeing NEC 334.30 which calls out the need to secure cables within 12" of each box.  Do the clamps in an old work box cover NEC 334.30 as well?

Comment: @dpollitt Related https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/155931/securing-cable-when-installing-old-work-box

Comment: That question/answer covers it!  No staple needed. And I do have attic access so I’ll try to fish it down from there. Thanks!