# How to handle a break in a circuit due to removal of a fixture?

Tags: electrical, drywall

[image: jbox i no longer want]
[image: overview of area]

<sub>(For purposes of this question, ignore the second circuit with the three way switch and 2 14/3 nm cables on the right hand side of the open area.)</sub>

I have to relocate the ceiling fixture switch in a bedroom.  The fixture was getting power from the middle of a run of nm cable.  As as temporary solution I've simply tied together the two cables with nuts in the j box, but I'd like to remove this box before drywalling the area.  I realize that it is not going to be up to code to simply hide the connection within a wall, but I'm not sure what other options are out there.  Of course my preference is not to have a box and blank plate visible in the bedroom, and I'd prefer to rip out less drywall over more.

Comment: I’m sure this is a very common scenario, I’m just not sure what to even search for to get help with this. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Let us know what state you're in (i.e. location, not alcohol consumption or holiday frenzy level :D ), and someone will likely come up with a code-compliant solution for you.

Comment: @FreeMan - Minnesota USA, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you understand the constraint of having the splice in a box. Like a lot of people on here, I am weary about in-wall splice products like the one mentioned in JACK's answer, although I admit I don't have much experience using them.

I would look very closely at the possibility of running a new cable. Sometimes it can be easier than you think and might not involve too much drywall damage/repair. Assuming the cable terminates at the receptacle on the left, I would start there. Remove the receptacle and disconnect all the wiring. Use a hacksaw blade to cut the nails that hold the junction box to the stud and remove the box.  Reach into the hole and try to remove the staples that fasten the cable to the stud near the box.  Then  fasten a string or fish line to the cable and pull the cable through the studs back towards the wall area you have open.  With a little luck the cable will pull through and you can use the string to pull a length of new cable.  When you are all done, don't forget to replace the box you just removed with a new "old work" style box that clamps the drywall edge to hold it in place.

We can't see where the other end of the cable goes, but if it goes to another box close by you might be able to repeat the process on the other end, or maybe by just replacing one side of the cable, you would have enough freedom to move the box to a more desirable location, like higher up on the wall where the box could be hidden behind a clock or wall art.  Although it doesn't look like it would apply in this case, if you could move the splice towards the floor you could put a box with an outlet there and not have a "weird" box in the center of the wall with a blank plate on it.

Don't forget to consider the what is on the other side of the wall.  Depending on how you use the space, the other side of the wall could be a better place to have the junction box, and it would not be too much work to cut a hole in the drywall and mount the box the other way.

Comment: Smart, reasonable answer. This is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: If you end up replacing the box below the TV in order to pull a new length of cable, consider pulling another length of cable up the wall and adding a new box with an outlet behind the TV if there is not one there already. No more unsightly power cords coming down the wall.

Comment: I don't see a lot of people weary about these splices. Maybe you should check them out.

Comment: @bigchief - Sadly, this loft is about to turn into a nursery and the baby won’t be enjoying a TV anytime soon :)

Comment: I’m happy to report back, I took your advice and it was mostly successful. I used a small hacksaw to remove the existing box and reached my hand in with a small bar to remove staples. That proved unsuccessful as the staples were just too awkward to get leverage on. After a few small drywall holes to gain access, I replaced the full length of cable successfully.

Answer (score 1):

There are straight splices available at many home stores that can be buried in the walls without a junction box.

[image]

Picture from Lowes

Comment: Home improvement stores carry products all the time that won’t meet common inspections or NEC code. I’m far from an expert, do you think this would commonly pass inspection?  I do not mean to be rude and appreciate the comment!

Comment: @dpollitt   In my experience, the big home stores (Home depot, Lowes) won't sell items that don't need code. You can't buy  NM cable in Chicago because local codes don't allow it.  These splices are UL listed, I've used them and they are great.  I think they were developed because people were just wire nutting splices in walls.

Comment: @JACK Oh, yes they will! Try buying a NEMA 10-30 recep :) or a non-TR recep or a 2-prong recep.   It'll be much worse if you ask advice from the stockchild, ask for a dryer socket and you'll be handed a 10-30, say "my cord is 4-prong though" and you'll be handed a 3-prong cord.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  They might not meet current code for new construction but they're still UL listed and can be used in old installations for the most part.  Yes, don't ask advice from anyone with a name tag on. I guess my main point is that the main home stores shouldn't be put in the same category  as Amazon as far as not meeting code.

Comment: These are great! the trades refer to them as tyco or Teco splices they are listed for in wall splices and I use them on remodels all the time. Even if not listed for new construction which they are this is a remodel. Other than this if a box is used I make a picture frame and mount the Sheetrock so it is removable totally legal if the finish is not damaged by removing a panel designed for access., I love how internet only electricians try and make a case agents items they don’t have experience with.+